# How do I maintain cursor in a database connection after connection dropped off?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector

Suppose I have a database(say, in `Snowflake`) and I need to perform some action on the results (something which cannot be done in `Snowflake`, like hitting an api with the result as input).

So I write a connector in `Python`. However, the connector fails in between. How do I get back till what point the data had been read, and resume from that point?

If the connection had not broken, I would have a `cursor` for exactly that. My question is, how do I keep `cursor` information, and use that after a connection drop?

One possible way is to keep writing the number of rows read to a local file, and when a new connection is established, bypass those number of rows already read and then resume from there. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but have you looked into external functions on Snowflake?  That would actually allow you to execute an external API directly from Snowflake with the results of a SQL query as the input to the API.

Comment: Will look into them. Attaching a link for future readers: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html#label-external-functions-introduction-miniglossary-external-function

Answer (score 1):

You can't get your cursor back after you disconnect since you need to open a new session when you connect again.

You could use a combination of `limit` and `offset` but you'll need to make sure you store your offset state somewhere local and ensure you have deterministic ordering of the results. That way you can reconnect, re-run the same query and use the local offset to read the next chunk of records. This will allow you to do it in batches rather than for each record since, even if you've disconnected, you'll still have batch of cursor results in memory untill you have to do your next fetch.

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/limit.html)

> An ORDER BY clause is not required; however, without an ORDER BY clause, the results are non-deterministic because results within a result set are not necessarily in any particular order. To control the results returned, use an ORDER BY clause

Actually, you should use an `order by` clause which returns results in a  deterministic way (like ordering on a primary key / unique identifier for each row)